# Polyfit and Polyval in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to understand the functions **polyval** and **polyfit**. 
At First I programming in Matlab the following lines:

```
x               = (0:.01:95)/180*pi;
y               = polyval(cooefs_w_0(end:-1:1), x);
[p,~,mu]        = polyfit(y, x, 5);
```

My first question is: The result from polyfit is not the same if I write this line:

```
p               = polyfit(y, x, 5);
```

Why? The Variable **p** must be the same.

Comment: Functions can change their output depending on how many output arguments you specify. `p` is different here because the 3rd output argument changes how the function operates.

Answer (score 2):

The `3rd` output argument, changes the independent variable from

```
y
```

to

```
normalized_y = (y-means(y))/std(y)
```

This is called **normalization**, the new `normalized_y` will have `0` as **mean** and `1` as **standard deviation**

**Why normalization?**

- If the independent variable `y` can be fitted to a **Gaussian Distribution**, this will lead to a **better** polynomial coefficient
  estimation than non-normalized method
- If it can't be fitted to  a **Gaussian Distribution** there is no need
  to normalize `y`, as **normalized method** gives similar results compared to the **non-normalized method**

---

**Proof** `[p, ~mu] = polyfit(...)` **uses a normalized input**

```
% I increase the step to make the plot clear
x               = (0:5:95)/180*pi;

cooefs_w_0 = [1,4, 5, 9];
y               = polyval(cooefs_w_0(end:-1:1), x);
% y normalization
normalized_y = (y-mean(y))/std(y);

[p,~,mu]        = polyfit(y, x, 5);
% polyfit with one output argument but input changed to the normalized y
p_normalized        = polyfit(normalized_y, x, 5);

% Check if the coefficients are the same 
isequal(p, p_normalized);
% ans =

  logical

   1
```

---

**Estimate dependent variable `x` using** `polyval()`

- ***Without normalization***, just use the coefficients obtained from the fitting

```
p_original          =   polyfit(y, x, 5);
original_prediction =   polyval(p_original, y);
```

- ***With normalization***, use the coefficients obtained from the fitting and the
  real mean and standard deviation of the independent variable `y` specified by `mu`

```
[p,~,mu]               =   polyfit(y, x, 5);
normalized_prediction  =   polyval(p, y, [], mu);
```

Since `y` is not well fitted to a Gaussian distribution, the two estimations are similar but not exactly the same

> ## Graph  [image]